# ElasticSearch index topology - field overrides

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm curious as to whether it is possible to set an index structure and query within ElasticSearch so that the following operation can be achieved in as few queries as possible.

Let's define a few things present in the system.

- A **document** has a bunch of info related to its source, data type, etc. For simplification, we'll give them three fields: `id`, `tone`, `date`. There are some fulltext elements to it but they've all been dealt with already
- A **report** has a bunch of info related to search queries. For our purposes, they're stored separately. They also have an id, which we refer to as `idReport`
- A **clip** is the link between a **report** and a **document**. It is represented as an `id`-`idReport` mapping, which can have an optional third field: an override for `tone`

The key snag in our system is that the `tone` present in the associative link needs to override the `tone` present on the document for all facets, but cannot replace it. Some reports may see a document as positive, while others see it as neutral, or even positive.

I was thinking of storing the report link as a nested field within document. Effectively, a document would then be as follows:

```
 {
   id: integer,
   tone: integer,
   reports: [
      { id: integer,
        tone: integer
      }
   ]
 }
```

The key issue with this is whether it is possible, *in one query* to seamlessly override the tone with anything present in the nested field. If not, what would be the best way forward?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's possible using [script fields](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-script-fields.html) in 1 query.

What I'd do is restructure nested reports as an object like so:

```
  {
     id: integer,
     tone: integer,
     reports: {
       idA: {
         tone: integer
       } ,
       idB: {
         tone: integer
       } 
     }
   }
```

And then have a query like so, which returns 'toneWithFallback' as a field with the content you want:

```
    {
        "query" : {
           ...
        },
        "script_fields" : {
            "toneWithFallback" : {
                "script" : "_source.reports[reportId].empty || _source.reports[reportId].tone.empty ? _source.reports[reportId].tone: _source.tone ",
                "params" : {
                    "reportId"  : "<theIdAsAString>"
                }
            }
        }
   }
```

You can also [filter](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-script-filter.html), [sort](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-sort.html#_script_based_sorting) , or [facet](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-facets-terms-facet.html#_term_scripts) by a script.